# Filtered sheet not editing back into the main excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet filtered in excel based on a Microsoft query. Now when I make changes to the main sheet, it reflects back in the filtered sheet.

But this doesn't happen otherwise. I would like to use the filtered sheet to make changes to the main one.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Under the tab "Formulas" you can set "Calculation Options". It should work if it is set to "Automatic".